# How do I create material popup for each item created by ngFor?

Tags: dart, angular-material, angular-dart

I am trying to create a material popup select that will allow me to change a variable for each material chip that I have. My popup/material select is not being duplicated. Instead, it is the same popup on each chip. statusDropdowns contains New, In Progress, On Hold, Complete, and Canceled.

I have tried changing different parts of the popup and the material-select-item. I also tried ngFor on material-select and that only created a dropdown

```
 <material-chips class="clickable chips" *ngFor="let t of taskList">
                <material-chip
                *ngIf="t.joinID == p.id"
                [ngClass]="{'new': t.tStatus == 'New', 'inprogress': t.tStatus == 'In Progress', 'onhold': t.tStatus == 'On Hold', 'complete': t.tStatus == 'Complete', 'canceled': t.tStatus == 'Canceled'}"
                [removable]="false"
                popupSource
                #source="popupSource"
                buttonDecorator
                (trigger)="showPopup(source)"
                materialTooltip="{{t.genNotes}}"
                (click)="onTaskSelect(t)"
                [class.selected]="p  === taskSelected">
                <div>{{t.tName}}</div>
                <div style="font-size: 10px">{{t.sTech}}</div>
                <material-popup [source]="popSource" 
                                [(visible)]="showingPopup" 
                                [enforceSpaceConstraints]="false" 
                                [preferredPositions]="[position]">
                    <div header style="background: lightblue; color: black; font-weight: bold; line-height: 1.8; text-align: center">
                        Select Project Status
                    </div>
                  <material-select width="2" class="bordered-list">
                      <material-select-item *ngFor="let s of statusDropdowns"
                                            (trigger)="proto = s"
                                            [selected]="proto == s">{{s}}</material-select-item>
                    </material-select>
                  </material-popup>
              </material-chip>
            </material-chips>
```

There should be a separate dropdown list corresponding to the t.tStatus of each material-chip.

Comment: Expecting Stackblitz!

Comment: I didn't use Stackblitz because I am pulling all of my info from a local MongoDB server. I can make an example in Stackblitz but it will take just a bit!